# Прижатый к низу footer с помощь bootstrap3

Tags: css, bootstrap

Подскажите класс в bootstrap3 отвечающий за прижатие footer к низу страницы когда контента на странице меньше чем высота окна просмотра в браузере.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть класс `navbar-fixed-bottom`, но он делает футер фиксированым.
В офф. документации предложено [такое решение](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/).